# iDevice browser, change content of selection menu

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, ipad, mobile

If I select something on an iDevice browser a menu shows up (copy, paste etc)

Is it possible to add things via javascript to this menu?

The menu I mean (here it contains; 'copy')
[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible, Apple has option this in the Safari DOM.